# Why does this comparison return false?

Tags: c

In this little program:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    uint8_t a = 0;
    uint8_t b = 255;

    if (a == (b + 1)) {
        printf("Equal\n");
    } else {
        printf("Not equal\n");
    }

    if (a == ((b + 1) & 0xFF)) {
        printf("Equal\n");
    } else {
        printf("Not equal\n");
    }       
}
```

I get:

```
Not Equal
Equal
```

Why doesn't the comparison work unless I forcibly take the last 8 bits?  I'm guessing I'm missing some nuance of unsigned arithmetic here...

I'm using gcc 4.4.5 if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because of integer promotions, both operands of the `==` and `+` operator are promoted to `int`.

The expression:

```
a == (b + 1)
```

is then equivalent to:

```
0 == 256
```

which is false.

The expression: `a == (uint8_t) (b + 1)` would give you the result you expect (true). Another solution is to use `& 0xFF` like in your second `if` statement,

Comment: Aha, I had never heard of that before, that would do it.

Comment: It's not the operands of `==` that matter, it's those of `+`.

Comment: I would _never_ have guessed that! Good thinking.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth corrected, also kept the `==` operator as `a` is also promoted.

Answer (score 2):

`1` is an integer, so the expression is promoted to `int`. With this type, the comparison gets `0 == 256`. In the other case, you're forcing the *and* with just the 8 digits, so the comparison holds.